# Why are two diffeomorphims of $R^n$ are always homotopic (in the same category)?

Tags: homotopy-theory, knot-theory

Where can one find the proof of the following fact:

If there are two orientation-preserving diffeomorphisms $\phi_0$ and $\phi_1$ of $R^n$, then there exists a homotopy $\phi(t)$, such that $\phi(0)$ = $\phi_0$, $\phi(1)$ = $\phi_1$, and $\phi(t)$ is a diffeomorphism for any $t$ (and $\phi$ is smooth for all variables).

This is easy to prove for $n=1$, and relatively easy for $n=2$, but for an arbitrary $n$ seems difficult.

This fact is used in the knot theory to justify the coincidence of two definitions of the knot equivalence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

An explicit deformation retraction of $\mathrm{Diff}(\mathbb R^n)$ onto $\mathrm{Aff}(\mathbb R^n)$ is given by $$f_t(x)=f(0)+\frac{f(tx)-f(0)}{t}$$ for $t\in (0,1]$ and $f_0(x)=f(0)+f^\prime(0)x$.

Comment: Actually, both answers give the same approach. For me, the second one has a more compact form.

Answer (score 11):

By a one parameter family of translations, get the origin fixed.
By a one parameter family of linear transformations, get the derivative at the origin to be the identity matrix. 
Conjugate by a dilation.
Send the dilation parameter to infinity.
Look at the Taylor series: it is going to the identity.
I think the rest is easy from there.